# Generate permutations using a list and single value or list and list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to achieve following results

```
import itertools 
i = [1, 2, 3]
```

The following does not work...How do I create all the combinations using an iterable with a single value?

```
allCombos = [combo for combo in itertools.product(i, True)]
# I want to yield (1, True), (2, True), (3, True)
```

This is working for the other case

```
if includeFalse:
    allCombos = [combo for combo in itertools.product(i, [True, False])]
    # yields in (1, True), (1, False), (2, True), (2, False), (3, True), (3 False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put your single value in a list, and use:

```
allCombos = [combo for combo in itertools.product(i, [True])]
```

Or you could just have a simple list comprehension:

```
allCombos = [(x, True) for x in i]
```